# Como puedo conectar la base de datos de python con flask para realizar un CRUD

Tags: python, mysql, flask

tengo una duda, estoy siguiente el codigo de un video tutorial donde ya instale los paquetes solicitados para trabajar con las base de datos en python y el codigo hasta el momento lo tengo asi:

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask import render_template
    from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
    
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
    mysql = MySQL()
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST']='localhost'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER']='root'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD']=''
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB']='sistema'
    mysql.init_app(app)
    
    
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
    
        sql="INSERT INTO `empleados` (`id`, `nombre`, `correo`, `foto`) VALUES (NULL, 'Miguel', 'miguelberrio@gmail.com', 'foto_perfil.jpg');"
        conn= mysql.connect()
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
    
    
        return render_template('empleados/index.html')
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

pero al momento de ejecutar en un navegador para ingresar al servicor y mostrar en la pagina lo que escribi en el archivo html me sale error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flaskext\mysql.py", line 5, in from flask import _app_ctx_stack as _ctx_stack ImportError: cannot import name 'app_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask_init.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\PythonProjects\Main_project\app.py", line 4, in from flaskext.mysql import MySQL File "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flaskext\mysql.py", line 7, in from flask import _request_ctx_stack as _ctx_stack ImportError: cannot import name 'request_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask_init.py)
```

entonces no se como puedo acomodarlo, alguno me podria indicar cual es el error, sabiendo que lo estoy haciendo de acuerdo a lo indicado en el video tutorial. La version con la que estoy trabajando en los paquetes de flask es la version 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

el problema que estas experimentado probablemente sea la versión que estas utilizando y como integras flask.mysql en él.

Considera usar flask_mysqldb que es una versión actualizada para las versiones más recientes de flask.

Instala el paquete con el siguiente comando:

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Y te proporciono una versión modificada de tu código:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'sistema'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    
    sql = "INSERT INTO `empleados` (`id`, `nombre`, `correo`, `foto`) VALUES (NULL, 'Miguel', 'miguelberrio@gmail.com', 'foto_perfil.jpg');"
    cur.execute(sql)
    
    mysql.connection.commit()
    cur.close()

    return render_template('empleados/index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Espero esto solucione tu problema.